# "brew install ogre" fails at "make install"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm stuck at installing `ogre` via `brew`. The error output seems limited to me and I'm not experienced OSX user at all. Any idea is appreciated.

```
$ brew install ogre
==> Downloading https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/ogre/1.7/ogre_src_v1-7-4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre-1.7.4.tar.bz2
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/raw/4237236/e357f1b9fa8b26d02ed84f411d5b5eb7446c68c5/pkg_config_fix.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-f9100fef2823227803f14e1676818ed17a89e895.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/raw/4237236/57cb907304433cc0bb83fd332ff98a5789102b00/prevent_framework_apple.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-019c0c8f82ffd6c7dd258676c4f04b9881695e43.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/raw/4237236/31ae53cefdb693cb2fb81333178163a29f8cf7ca/osx_isystem.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-e750d6cb9f2b0123ef28dda4e024db98625fde76.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/raw/4237236/9c7df6689da4e0b358429692f6615f2707469f45/osx_linking.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-2855209c15422cc8df3110f9a0e32e084cd1e5b6.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/raw/4237236/d667813d5ee1e712e0ea8cc99df9a85da6141b1e/replace_pbxcp_with_ditto.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-3d2e4054643189273450245e15182f406125c94b.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/wjwwood/5672104/raw/bf69b4528b3090ad99a760029beb75b7aeb11248/fix_boost_linking.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-73d730e4fbc01ce06d9137a495b0a52488ca71e8.patch
==> Downloading https://gist.github.com/hgaiser/7346167/raw/3167c2fde153618e55b37f857ef4a90cc54ed2a3/ogre.patch
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ogre--patch-6cf5fc081d291b7f9bc9ce3dd4019cc18b16b4b9.patch
==> Patching
patching file CMake/Templates/OGRE.pc.in
patching file OgreMain/CMakeLists.txt
patching file CMakeLists.txt
patching file CMake/Dependencies.cmake
Hunk #1 succeeded at 123 with fuzz 1.
patching file CMake/Packages/FindFreetype.cmake
patching file Components/Paging/CMakeLists.txt
patching file Components/Property/CMakeLists.txt
patching file Components/RTShaderSystem/CMakeLists.txt
patching file Components/Terrain/CMakeLists.txt
patching file OgreMain/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/BSPSceneManager/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/CgProgramManager/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/OctreeSceneManager/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/OctreeZone/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/PCZSceneManager/CMakeLists.txt
patching file PlugIns/ParticleFX/CMakeLists.txt
patching file CMake/Dependencies.cmake
Hunk #1 succeeded at 134 with fuzz 1.
patching file RenderSystems/GL/src/OSX/OgreOSXCocoaWindow.mm
patching file RenderSystems/GL/src/OSX/OgreOSXGLSupport.mm
==> cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES='x86_64' -DOGRE_BUILD_PLUGIN_CG=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/ogre/1.7.4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=O
==> make install
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreFont.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/issues
```

Some diagnosis:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 24cc097d27661169e5b96da8ddb4b8cfebbc5086
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.9.2-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
Clang: 5.1 build 503
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

---

Update) Full log: http://pastebin.com/AFhNZ18w

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp.o
cd /tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/build/OgreMain && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DFREEIMAGE_LIB -DOGRE_NONCLIENT_BUILD -DOgreMain_EXPORTS -D_MT -D_USRDLL -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fPIC -I/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/include -I/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/build/include -I/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/include/OSX -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers -I/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/nedmalloc    -pthread -o CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp.o -c /tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp
/tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/src/OgreFont.cpp:44:10: fatal error: 'freetype.h' file not found
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
         ^
/usr/local/include/freetype/config/ftheader.h:173:24: note: expanded from macro 'FT_FREETYPE_H'
#define FT_FREETYPE_H  <freetype.h>
                       ^
1 error generated.
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /tmp/ogre-4JyI/ogre_src_v1-7-4/build/CMakeFiles 
[ 12%] make[2]: *** [OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreFont.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What's the output when you run `brew install -v ogre`? The `-v` runs the install in verbose mode.

Comment: @Ian C. Thanks. I've updated my OP. Looks like `freetype` isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked this around by myself. 
Actually the problem seems to be involved when I followed [this instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#os.2BAC8-OSX.2BAC8-Homebrew.2BAC8-troubleshooting.PIL_fails_to_install_on_OS_X_10.9_.28Mavericks.29) to create a symlink like this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

After I removed the symlink, `brew` worked successfully.